# Why margin property is not working in the "container3" after using "clear" property (css)?

Tags: html, css, css-float

All 3 containers that you see in the attached file are inside one main container. I used "**float: left**" for the 1st two containers and "**clear: both**" property to the 3rd.

But, it seems like after applying "**clear**" property to the third container, **margin-top** isn't working.

Please help me with the following questions :

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Code :

```
    div#insideContainer1
{
      max-width:        500px;
      padding:          20px;
      box-sizing:       border-box;
      border:           1px solid #e0e0e0;
      border-radius:    5px;

      float:            left;
}

div#insideContainer2
{
      max-width:        500px;
      padding:          20px;
      box-sizing:       border-box;
      border:           1px solid #e0e0e0;
      border-radius:    5px;

      margin-left:      20px;
      float:            left;
}

div#insideContainer3
{
      max-width:        500px;
      padding:          20px;
      box-sizing:       border-box;
      border:           1px solid #e0e0e0;
      border-radius:    5px;

      margin-top:       30px;
      clear:            both;
}
```

[CSS Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqgQo.png)

[CSS Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7D6V.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include your code and the simplest way to reproduce your issue in your question

Comment: Sure @Joundill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright then,
1- When `clear: both;` a div, you clear what's beside it on left and right, so div#3 clear is doing nothing...

(for example: if you give both div#1 and div#2 `clear: both;` each div will take it's own block and it ruin the `float: left;`

2- To break the float in this case, you don't need `clear" both;` in any of these divs, it'll be a **div itself** to clear and sperate!

3- Since the divs has the same CSS style, we should select all at once (read more: CSS Selector Reference).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1"></div> 
    <div class="div2"></div>
    <div class="clear-both"></div> 
    <div class="div3"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div1,
.div2,
.div3{
    width: 500px;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f40b0b;
    margin: 10px;
}

.div1, .div2 {
    float: left;
}

.div3 {
    background-color: aqua;
}

.clear-both {
    clear: both;
}
```